# Find if date is older than 2 months in PHP

Tags: php

I have customer `registered_date` in DB. Now I need to insert some values for this customer table base on this `registered_date` field.

Formula is something like this, if `registered_date` is old 2 months for current date, the value should be added to DB, or its old more than 2 months it should not be inserted.

I tried it something like this:

```
$added = new DateTime( '2016-06-01' );
//$end = $added->modify( '+2 month' );
$interval = new DateInterval('P2M');

$checkDate = $added->sub($interval);
$checkDate->format('Y-m-d');

if($added < $checkDate ) {
  echo "insert"; 
} else {
  echo "not insert";
}
```

But, its not working for me.

Hope somebody may help me out. 
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
//if registered_date is older then 2 months from current date
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$registered_date = new DateTime('2016-06-05');

$now = new DateTime();
$interval = new DateInterval('P2M');
$checkDate = $now->sub($interval);

if($registered_date > $checkDate ) {
  echo "insert";
} else {
  echo "not insert";
}
```